# Highlight Active Menu using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

- I have a `sidebar` with few `<li>` elements in it. as shown below

```
     <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item active  ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">
              <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./overview.html">
              <i class="material-icons">explore</i>
              <p>Overview</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./user.html">
              <i class="material-icons">person</i>
              <p>User Profile</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./tables.html">
              <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
              <p>Table List</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./typography.html">
              <i class="material-icons">library_books</i>
              <p>Typography</p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

[[image]

- When I click on other tabs such as `Overview` , `User Profile` , i want that purple highlight to be active on that

  class.

> How do i achieve that using jquery?

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.sidebar-wrapper a').click(function(e){
        .....

      });
    });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the navigation is not client side. You should listen to document ready event; when the page loads find the link with current location and highlight it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var link = $('.nav').find('a[href=".' + window.location.pathname + '"]');
   link.parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Also make sure you remove `active` class from other links :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following. Firstly, remove the `active` class from all the li's and then apply `active` class to the li which is the parent of the clicked a.

Please note, just added `e.preventDefault()` for example here and may not be required in actual code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-wrapper a').click(function(e) {
      $('.sidebar-wrapper li').removeClass("active");
      $(e.currentTarget).parent().addClass("active");
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.active > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item active  ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">
        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
        <p>Dashboard</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="./overview.html">
        <i class="material-icons">explore</i>
        <p>Overview</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="./user.html">
        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
        <p>User Profile</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="./tables.html">
        <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
        <p>Table List</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="./typography.html">
        <i class="material-icons">library_books</i>
        <p>Typography</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```